# How to show an image view only if the model object contains image url

Tags: ios, swift, facebook, cell, collectionview

So I am creating a facebook feed of sorts and I am fetching text, url for images/videos and username etc. The cell I have created has an image view, text view and label. I am sizing the cell according to the text view content size.

Now lets say the user has only posted text and there no image with it. I want the cell to be sized so that there is no image view in the cell. Only the text view and thats it.

Can this be done using just one cell/model/adapter or do I need custom cells and show them according to the model.

A little light on how this could be done would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You just need one cell and there are different ways of achieving this. A simple oen is using a UIStackView inside the cell.

When one element of the UIStackView is hidden, it adapts it size. If you place constraints from to the stack view to the cell, the cell with be smaller/larger depending if you show the image. You just have to work with constraints.

Also, using UIStackView or not, remember to specify on your tableView that the size of the cell will be dynamic by doing:

```
self.tableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension
```

Comment: Not a bad idea. I might try using UIStackView. Thanks for the suggestion!

Answer (score 0):

Create a outlet of image height constraint, and then check if your URL is blank or invalid then make height constraint constant 0 otherwise give it appropriate height.

And make sure you have implemented both the methods :

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, estimatedHeightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
    return 100; // Put estimated height
}
```

And another one is,

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
    return UITableViewAutomaticDimension
}
```

Comment: Let me try this one out as well. Thanks for the idea!